# Using Ionic 2/3, how to provide specific content for in-app-purchase?

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

Let's I have an in-app-purchase app built in Ionic 2 or Ionic 3. On a purchase I want to provide a resource (image or json file). How and where to host that content?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: In the assets folder, create a folder specific to both image and json seperately. and you can include it in your app on your needs. Give me a feedback if its what you needed.

Comment: I understand that's the most place to stage that content. Then it also means that everybody gets that content. If security is compromised, then that content is there.
I want the content to be downloaded only upon a purchase. How to make that happen?

Comment: If you don't want it to be shown at any case and you are tensed about security concerns, why don't you pass the content from the server then?

Comment: Or if you plan to put it in the client side any ways, then create a service that enables you to get the item only when the purchase is complete, not before that. Enable the download option after the purchase. So that you can place the content in the assets folder, but you get the authorization to download it only when you purchase it

Comment: Thank you. I will do it that way. It may mean verifying the receipt, but that's fine.